# RewriteRule to cause subdomain to load another DocumentRoot?

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, subdomain, document-root

Apache (mostly) noob here... could sure use a little help with what I am trying to do with a `RewriteRule` in `.htaccess`:
...to causes URLs using our `sharpedge.` subdomain to auto-load from the `Internet_IE` directory - one level deeper than the site root.

I have this in `httpd.conf`:

```
[snip]
NameVirtualHost 11.22.33.44

<VirtualHost 11.22.33.44>
    Options All +ExecCGI
    ServerAdmin hostmaster@ourhost.com
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html/ourdomain.com
    ServerName ourdomain.com
    ServerAlias www.ourdomain.com
    DirectoryIndex index.htm index.html index.dna
    #---------------------------------
    <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization},L]
    </IfModule>
    #---------------------------------
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost 11.22.33.44>
    Options All +ExecCGI
    ServerAdmin hostmaster@ourhost.com
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html/ourdomain.com
    ServerName  sharpedge.ourdomain.com
    DirectoryIndex index.htm index.html index.dna
    #---------------------------------
    <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization},L]
    </IfModule>
    #---------------------------------
</VirtualHost>
[snip]
```

...and this in .htaccess (in the site root, here: /var/www/html/ourdomain.com/)

```
Options -Indexes

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /

    RewriteCond   %{HTTP_HOST} ^sharpedge\.ourdomain\.com$
    # years ago this next line was used here, but in httpd.conf: (I don't know what it was supposed to do)
    # RewriteRule   ^(.+)        %{HTTP_HOST}$1          [C]
    RewriteRule   ^sharpedge\.ourdomain\.com(.*) /var/www/html/ourdomain.com/Internet_IE/$1  [L]
</IfModule>
```

..but nothing happens from the RewriteRule; it is as if the RewriteRule was not there.

I'd much appreciate any suggestions.

Edits:

- I would just change the DocumentRoot to the directory I actually want to serve, but I need to be able to call (include) files from within files in that directory with a prefixing `/` in the include path, where those files are located in the site root.  Those files are also similarly called from other files that are in the site root.

Comment: Why not just set `DocumentRoot` to whatever directory you like for this vhost in first place?

Comment: thanks poncha, I neglected to add a crucial point to my OP about why that does not work for me... which I just added to the end of my OP.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't want to put any part of your host in the `RewriteRule`, but you got the HTTP_HOST right, try:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^sharpedge\.ourdomain\.com$ [NC]
# to prevent looping
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /Internet_IE/$1 [L]
```

---

Try changing the `!-f` and `!-d` checks:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^sharpedge\.ourdomain\.com$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/Internet_IE/
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /Internet_IE/$1 [L]
```

Comment: @govinda Are you sure you have the rewrite module loaded?

Comment: Yes, when I do this: `RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} !^11\.22\.33\.44$` , 
`RewriteRule ^fileNameActuallyLoaded/?(.*) http://zzz.ourdomain.com/ [R=301,L]`, then it does redirect to the bogus (just for this test) domain `zzz.ourdomain.com`.

Comment: hooray!  That did it.  Rhetorical Q: why is Apache config. such a bear?  Even the server admins by trade seems to treat it like a house of cards; no one wants to touch it once they manage to beat it into this month's needful behavior.  We code way harder things, and have an easier time at it.  Anyway, bless you.

Comment: @govinda Unfortunately, the rewrite engine rules (and Apache config in general) isn't really like a nice, well thought out, scripting language. It's sort of an as-needed hacked together, not very well thought out, set of commands that may, or may not, work well together. It solves some problems well like they were designed to do, but when people start doing tricky things, it's not so predictable anymore